# CATransition animation key always "transition"

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-graphics

Got a basic CATranisition. Works.

```
        animationKey = @"fadeIn";

        [self.icon setImage:self.iconSelected];
        [self.shadow setAlpha:1.0];
        CATransition *transitionIn = [CATransition animation];
        transitionIn.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        transitionIn.delegate = self;
        transitionIn.duration = 1.2;
        transitionIn.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        transitionIn.type = kCATransitionFade;

        [self.icon.layer addAnimation:transitionIn forKey:animationKey];
        [self.shadow.layer addAnimation:transitionIn forKey:animationKey];
        [CATransaction commit];
```

Here's the rub tho:

```
        [self.icon.layer animationForKey:animationKey]
```

always returns NULL.

When I do:

```
        [self.icon.layer animationKeys]
```

I get:

```
        icon keys: (
transition
         )
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CALayer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) says "The special key kCATransition is automatically used for transition animations."